# Is there any way to record external audio from a Canon Rebel R6?

Tags: audio, canon, microphone

I am looking at buying a Canon Rebel T6 to record video, but would like to have better audio than the built in microphone. Is there any way, with an adapter or otherwise, that I can use this camera to record video with externally supplied audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Welcome to Video Production Stack Exchange!**

**Bad news first-**

Unfortunately, you are stuck with the in-camera mic with the T6. The ***T6i*** has a microphone jack for mounting an external microphone. If you want to mount an external mic to a Canon Rebel T6 body and record that audio stream to the same SD card, that's really your only option.

**However**

Can you elaborate a little on what your uses for the video are and what your workflow is?

I have shot on a T6 and T6i extensively and I eventually determined the workflow that was best for me was to use a Zoom H4N as my primary sound recorder (placed somewhere out of sight in the shot) and synced the audio streams together in Adobe Premiere during post production.

Comment: That's more or less what I've decided to do. Will record audio with a dedicated recorder, which actually will be kind of nice as I can set up the camera wherever will best work and not have to connect them together. Not what I expected, but will work. I currently use Adobe Premiere, and will do a test tonight to merge the two together, and a better test in a few days.

Comment: As you probably know, using a slate or having someone involved clap on-screen at the beginning will help sync the sources in post.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The first video I tried this with I just synced the source as heard by the camera as the one from the recording, and things seem to have worked out just fine. Still working on the focus, but... I'm getting this! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYQxzStuxzM